# makefile: warning: overriding recipe for target 'build'

Tags: makefile

I have a very simple makefile:

```
#Compiler flags
CC := gcc
INCLDIR := -I./includes

#Directories and files
BUILDDIR := ./build
STLIB := $(BUILDDIR)/libbinary_tree.a

$(BUILDDIR)/binary_tree.o: ./source_files/binary_tree.c | $(BUILDDIR)
    $(CC) -c $< $(INCLDIR) -o $@

$(BUILDDIR):
    mkdir $(BUILDDIR)

.PHONY: build
build: $(BUILDDIR)/binary_tree.o
    ar -rcs $(STLIB) $(BUILDDIR)/binary_tree.o
```

What I want to do:
with the command `make build` make from `./source_files/binary_tree.c` `./build/binary_tree.o` and create a static library from it. If `./build` doesn't exist - create the folder.
But I get some warnings:

```
makefile:17: warning: overriding recipe for target 'build'
makefile:13: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'build'
make: Circular build/binary_tree.o <- build dependency dropped.
ar -rcs ./build/libbinary_tree.a ./build/binary_tree.o
```

If I change in my file build to build2:

```
...
PHONY: build2
build2: ...
```

then `make build2` works without warning.
How can this be achieved using `make build` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have this:

```
BUILDDIR := ./build

$(BUILDDIR):
        mkdir $(BUILDDIR)

build: $(BUILDDIR)/binary_tree.o
       ar -rcs $(STLIB) $(BUILDDIR)/binary_tree.o
```

After variables are expanded make sees this:

```
./build:
        mkdir $(BUILDDIR)

build: ./build/binary_tree.o
       ar -rcs $(STLIB) $(BUILDDIR)/binary_tree.o
```

Make ignores initial `./`, so these two targets are the same.  That's why you get this error.

You can do one of the following:

First, rename the target you use to build things: it's *always* wrong to write a rule in make that tells make it will create one thing (in this case, `build`) but actually creates something else (in this case, `$(STLIB)`).  This rule should be written:

```
$(STLIB): $(BUILDDIR)/binary_tree.o
       ar -rcs $@ $^
```

Of you want to have a simple rule to build it, add one like this:

```
all: $(STLIB)
```

Or second, if you have to have a rule named `build` (not `all` as in my example) rename your directory containing built objects, from `build` to `obj` or something.

Or finally, don't use the order-only prerequisite method to create the `build` directory, so that you don't need to create a rule for it.  For example:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/binary_tree.o: ./source_files/binary_tree.c
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) -c $< $(INCLDIR) -o $@
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! `mkdir -p $(@D)` helped me!